# Given the solution of a RR, how can we find the BIG-O complexity?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

Suppose we have the solution to a recurrence relations as $c^n+n(\log(n))^2+(10n)^c$.  How can we determine the BIG-O complexity if we say that $c > 1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you do is to look at the relative growth rates of the terms. In this case, the fastest-growing one is $c^n$, so this is $O(c^n)$.

In detail, you'd show that $n \log^2 n = O(c^n)$ and $10^c n^c = O(c^n)$, for example by showing that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{10^c n^c}{c^n} = 0$.